# Save a list of strings in django sql-lite database from view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to save a list of strings in django sql-lite database from view. Here is my piece of code

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        tags=request.POST['tag']
        tweets=scrape(tags)
        tweets=preprocessing(tweets)
        tweet=Tweet()
        tweet.text='save the tweet'
        tweet.save()
        return render(request,'home.html',{"tweet":tweets})
    else:
        all_tweets=Tweet.objects.all
        return render(request,'home.html',{"old_tweet":all_tweets})
```

The following three-line can save a single string `(tweet)` in my database

```
tweet=Tweet()
tweet.text='save the tweet'
tweet.save()
```

But I have a list of strings `(tweets)` that I want to save in the database. I want to save the output of `preprocessing(tweets)` which is a list in my database. If I use a loop, I think it makes the process too much slow. Loop code is as follow

```
for tw in tweets:
            tweet=Tweet()
            tweet.text=tw
            tweet.save()
```

So is there any efficient way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not save the entire list into the database, that won't be a good design.

You can create a list of tweet model objects and use Django's [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method for storing them all at once.

```
objs = [Tweet(text=tw) for tw in tweets]
Tweet.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

Entire code:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        tags=request.POST['tag']
        tweets=scrape(tags)
        tweets=preprocessing(tweets)
        objs=[Tweet(text=tw) for tw in tweets]
        Tweet.objects.bulk_create(objs)
        return render(request,'home.html',{"tweet":tweets})
    else:
        all_tweets=Tweet.objects.all
        return render(request,'home.html',{"old_tweet":all_tweets})
```